# Customize input kafka topic name for Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Since @EnableBinding and @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT) were deprecated in favor to functions, I need to create a consumer that would read messages from Kafka topic.
My consumer function:

```
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Person> log() {
        return person -> {
            System.out.println("Received: " + person);
        };
    }
```

, application.yml configs

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        consumer:
          destination: messages
          contentType: application/json
```

Instead of connecting to topic **messages**, it keeps connecting to **log-in-0** topic.
How could I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.log-in-0.destination=messages
```